# Summary values on a Django Model with tens of millions of records

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a Django model developed on PostgreSQL with more than 20 Millions of records.

The large volume of data makes it impossible to get even a simple count of all rows.

```py
from myapp.models import LargeModel

len(LargeModel.objects.all())
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do *not* use `len(..)` *here*, since it will force loeading the 20 million records in memory.

You can obtain the number of records with [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
from myapp.models import LargeModel

LargeModel.objects.count()
```

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myapp_largemodel
```

If you use `len(..)` Django will *evaluate* the queryset, this means it will make a query like `SELECT * FROM myapp_largemodel`. It thus will loead the ~20 million records first in memory (if that is even possible), and then calculate `len(..)` on that list. But that will thus require large amounts of memory, CPU cycles, and network bandwidth. If you do not plan to do anything with these records anyway, that is inefficient use of recources.

or as the documentation on [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) says:

> A `count()` call performs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` behind the scenes, so you should **always use `count()` rather than loading all of the record** into Python objects and calling `len()` on the result (unless you need to load the objects into memory anyway, in which case `len()` will be faster).